# Need editing in array structure

Tags: php, arrays

How do I change following array format

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [reviews] => data 1 [reviews 2] =>data 2 ))
```

to this format.

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ([0] => Array([reviews] =>data 1) [1] => Array( [reviews 2] => data 2 ))
```

Comment: Show us your best attempt

Comment: apart from nothing, have you tried something? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$arr =  array (array('reviews' => 'data 1', 'reviews 2' =>'data 2' ));
foreach($arr[0] as $k=>$v){
  $newarr[0][] = array($k =>$v);
}
print_r($newarr);//Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [reviews] => data 1 ) [1] => Array ( [reviews 2] => data 2 ) ) )
```

Comment: I tried your code it does not produce the result that the OP wanted :)) I wonder... why did he accept it?

Comment: @AresDraguna check whole code with output also

Comment: done that :) your output is: `Array([0] => Array([reviews] => data 1) [1] => Array([reviews 2] => data 2))` the OP wanted: `Array ( [0] => Array ([0] => Array([reviews] =>data 1) [1] => Array( [reviews 2] => data 2 )))` which is not the same to me :-??

Comment: @AresDraguna ok updated with [0] index thanks

Comment: this is something else ;) Np! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $single){
    $newarr[$i] = $single;
    $i++;
}
```

try this

Comment: Returns the same format

Comment: goes to show that there is ALWAYS someone who will post an answer, regardless of how stupid the question is :)

Comment: @AresDraguna: Question is simple but i couldnt found out the answer .

Comment: because you haven't even tried :) let's make a bet... I will fix your issue in 5 minutes... tops wanna count?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't... if you are good at php...then show me how good you are!!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes as I said, here is my answer ;)

```
$test = array ( 0 => array ( 'reviews' => 'data 1', 'reviews 2' => 'data 2' ));
$new_arr = array();
foreach($test as $key => $value) {
   foreach($value as $k => $v) {
      $new_arr[$key][][$k] = $v;
   }
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

outputs:

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [reviews] => data 1 ) [1] => Array ( [reviews 2] => data 2 ) ) )`

I made it like this so you might understand something when you see it. Hope you will!

Comment: @varathanyajiv I hope you learn something from this experience... you know... you will NOT learn ANYTHING if you don't try it for yourself first... stay safe! :)